# Storing multiple binary values in a cookie

Tags: php, jquery, html, cookies

I have many polls on my site, and I want to prevent users from re-voting many times. As far as I know, I can either keep a IP log of visitors, or store cookies. I tried using an IP log into mySQL database, but theres one problem: All visitors behind a router have the same external IP so only one person behind the router can vote on a certain poll.

So now I'm switching my code to use cookies unless there are better solutions. Since there will eventually be hundreds or thousands of polls, and I think there is a 20 cookie limit, how can I store values for each poll? The values can just be binary values, for example poll1=0 if not yet voted, poll1=1 if voted.

Also, if it helps, each poll immediately shows the results using jquery. I'm assuming I can set/modify the cookie in the jquery resonse.

Any ideas? Thanks! (btw, I realize cookies can be deleted)

Comment: The last sentence makes whole question nonsensical.

Comment: Users are refer to anonymous users ? Or ?

Comment: Shrapnel: The polls are not that important to fully prevent multiple voting. If users want to go through the hassle of disabling cookies or deleting cookies, then I'll let them vote multiple times.


ajreal: I would prefer users to stay anonymous. No login or registration is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you may have hundreds of polls, it is reasonable to expect that each user will only vote in a few of those. So you can just have a single cookie with a comma-separated list of poll IDs in which the user has voted.

Of course, cookies don't provide any sort of protection since they can be deleted or tampered with, but they are also the only practical way to store such information and they work well in most cases.

Comment: Perhaps using a combination of both a logged ip and a cookie?

Comment: Thanks cacablanca, that may just work. I might comma-separate the poll numbers of the ones that have been voted on, like 14,238,728,235,38,382, etc... Would you know what happens if I surpass the 4KB cookie limit?

Comment: @Cody: I'm not sure what happens at the limit, I guess it is browser-dependent. But once again, you can easily store 500-1000 values or even more in 4KB, and it's highly unlikely that a single user will vote in so many.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to restrict per-user, you need to implement user identification, which means you need user registration, login and session management.  Once you have that, it's not at all difficult.  Just implement a many-to-many relation between your user records and your poll records with a join record created when a user takes a poll and checked to determine whether they've already taken it.

Trying to implement a limit on the activities of users without implementing a way of really identifying users will never work well.

Comment: The polls are not important enough to 100% restrict duplicate voting. I just wanted a small prevention system for users under normal circumstances to be able to vote only once. I didn't want users to have to register an account on the website. Though this way, I know users can work their way around duplicate voting if they put the effort into it.